# Running a console.log from an array thats inside a method of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

I was just learning about objects in school today and i know a function can be ran from inside an object, but the function is actually called a method, my method has an array and i like to get a particular destination to fire in the console.log by changing the global variable. Can this be done? All I'm getting is undefined at the last console.log -> ing at " + worker.getLocation.myLocation); So in all reality I'm trying to change the global variable, var myLocation = 0 to output the different myLocation inside getLocation method.

```
var myLocation = 0

var worker = {
    realName:       "Willson",
    title:          "Assistant Maintenance Supervisor",
    maintenance:    true,
    vehicals:       ["2008 Dodge Caliber SRT-4", "2012 Jeep Wrangler Unlimited"      ],
    getLocation:    function () { 
        myLocation [0] = "Villas at Sunrise Mountain";
        myLocation [1] = "Reno Villas"; 
        myLocation [2] = "lost"; 
        myLocation [3] = "back home";
    }
};

console.log(worker.realName + " is a " + worker.title + " and drives a " + worker.vehicals[1] + " to work."); 

var destination = {
    property: ["Villas at Sunrise Mountain", "Reno Villas", "lost", "back home"]
};

console.log ("He sold his " + worker.vehicals[0] + "." + " Today he is working at " + worker.getLocation.myLocation);
```

Comment: Initialize `myLocation` as an array using the bracket symbols, `[]`, since I see you are adding elements into it as if it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myLocation = 0

var worker = {
    realName:       "Willson",
    title:          "Assistant Maintenance Supervisor",
    maintenance:    true,
    vehicals:       ["2008 Dodge Caliber SRT-4", "2012 Jeep Wrangler Unlimited"      ],
    getLocation:    function () { 
        var myLocationss = [];
        myLocationss [0] = "Villas at Sunrise Mountain";
        myLocationss [1] = "Reno Villas"; 
        myLocationss [2] = "lost"; 
        myLocationss [3] = "back home";

        return myLocations[myLocation];

    }
};

console.log(worker.realName + " is a " + worker.title + " and drives a " + worker.vehicals[1] + " to work."); 

var destination = {
    property: ["Villas at Sunrise Mountain", "Reno Villas", "lost", "back home"]
};

console.log ("He sold his " + worker.vehicals[0] + "." + " Today he is working at " + worker.getLocation());
```

Comment: Thank you fliespl i knew it was something little i needed to change.